# Error using \limits

Tags: math-mode

My minimal TeX file

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \begin{document}

     \begin{align}\label{eq:time_marginal_condition}
        x \left\| x \right\|\limits_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R})}^{2}
     \end{align}
     \end{document}
```

I get the warnings

```
./test.tex:8: Limit controls must follow a math operator.
<argument> ...tion} x \left \| x \right \|\limits 
                                                  _{L^{2}(\mathbb {R})}^{2} 
l.8          \end{align}

./test.tex:8: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... x \right \|\limits _{L^{2}(\mathbb 
                                                  {R})}^{2} 
l.8          \end{align}

./test.tex:8: Limit controls must follow a math operator.
<argument> ...tion} x \left \| x \right \|\limits 
                                                  _{L^{2}(\mathbb {R})}^{2} 
l.8          \end{align}

./test.tex:8: Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ... x \right \|\limits _{L^{2}(\mathbb 
                                                  {R})}^{2} 
l.8          \end{align}
```

**How can you get rid of such warnings in the *align* environment?**

My unsuccessful attempt

```
\begin{align}\label{eq:time_marginal_condition}
            x \left\| x \right\|
            \limits_{L^{2}( \texorpdfstring{\mathbb{R}}{} )}^{2}
\end{align}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: @Jubobs I added the information here. The documentclass is *article*.

Comment: Still not compilable, though...

Comment: `\Int`........?

Comment: You simply forgot to add `\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}` as it was in the answer at your previous question. BTW: they are errors, not warnings...

Comment: @karlkoeller Not true. I add it here soon. I have it in the definitions.

Comment: @Masi karkoeller's comment was correct before your edit. Writing "not true" is dishonest...

Comment: Now it compiles fine for me. Does it not for you?

Comment: @DonutE.Knot \Int is \int\nolimits, from my answer to an earlier question. However how can one know it?

Comment: The error context from the error message doesn't match the MWE at all. Please show the error message you're getting with the example you posted here.

Comment: You are all right. My example was very bad, and I was wrong. I made now a minimal example of the problem which I did not see initially so clearly when I removed the relevant part in the TeX code.

Comment: The example does not generate warnings but errors, it isn't clear why you think it is at all related to align. `! Limit controls must follow a math operator.` is a remarkably clear error message from TeX `\|\limits` is a syntax error, you avoid the error by not doing that.

Comment: You should read some introductory material. For advanced math typesetting you can take a look at »[Math mode](http://ctan.org/pkg/mathmode)«.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Never* use `align` for a single equation. But it's not the cause for your problems. One is that you don't load `amssymb`, so `\mathbb` isn't defined. The second is that `\limits` doesn't make sense.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq:time_marginal_condition}
  x \lVert x \rVert_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R})}^{2}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Note that you shouldn't be using `\left\|` and `\right\|` unless you *need* the delimiter to grow.

The `\limits` keyword can be used after math operator such as `\sum` or `\int`, but makes no sense after `\rVert` or `\right\|`.

[image]

Comment: actually, `\mathbb` is defined in `amsfonts` (which is loaded by `amssymb`).  but that's not as important now that computers aren't tiny any more.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Whoever wants `\mathbb` probably needs also something from `amssymb`. `;-)`

Comment: What is wrong with align for a single equation?

Comment: @Paxinum For single equations the `displaymath` (also `\[...\]`) and `equation` environments do better spacing with respect to the preceding line; such adjustments are not done with multiline display environments (for TeXnical, but also typographically good reasons).

Answer (score 7):

Limit controls must be applied to a math operator.

Try this:

```
x \mathop{\left\| x \right\|}\limits_{L^{2}(\mathbb{R})}^{2}
```

[image]

PS: You forgot the `amssymb` package in your MWE.

Comment: Well, I've *never* seen such a notation.

Comment: Me neither. But to each their own :-) Of course it's not clear if this is even the intended result...

Comment: If you look at the edits in the question, I don't even know what the OP has really written in his document.

Comment: Well it seems @egreg was able to read the OPs mind anyway ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\mathop` before the symbol. For example `$\mathop\cap\limits_a^b$` will work.

Comment: Thanks @Mensch for improving the answer.